# Status Messagesに表示した項目の削除を行いたい

Tags: javascript, html5

項目の削除を行いたいのですが、
どのように実装したら良いか分かりません。
具体的には、アップロードした各ファイル名の右に削除ボタンを設け、ボタンを押下するとその項目が削除されるようにしたいです。

```js
/*
filedrag.js - HTML5 File Drag & Drop demonstration
Featured on SitePoint.com
Developed by Craig Buckler (@craigbuckler) of OptimalWorks.net
*/
(function() {

 // getElementById
 function $id(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
 }


 // output information
 function Output(msg) {
  var m = $id("messages");
  m.innerHTML = msg + m.innerHTML;
 }


 // file drag hover
 function FileDragHover(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.className = (e.type == "dragover" ? "hover" : "");
 }


 // file selection
 function FileSelectHandler(e) {

  // cancel event and hover styling
  FileDragHover(e);

  // fetch FileList object
  var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

  // process all File objects
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
   ParseFile(f);
  }

 }


 // output file information
 function ParseFile(file) {

  Output(
   "<p>File information: <strong>" + file.name +
   "</strong> type: <strong>" + file.type +
   "</strong> size: <strong>" + file.size +
   "</strong> bytes</p>"
  );

 }


 // initialize
 function Init() {

  var fileselect = $id("fileselect"),
   filedrag = $id("filedrag"),
   submitbutton = $id("submitbutton");

  // file select
  fileselect.addEventListener("change", FileSelectHandler, false);

  // is XHR2 available?
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if (xhr.upload) {

   // file drop
   filedrag.addEventListener("dragover", FileDragHover, false);
   filedrag.addEventListener("dragleave", FileDragHover, false);
   filedrag.addEventListener("drop", FileSelectHandler, false);
   filedrag.style.display = "block";

   // remove submit button
   submitbutton.style.display = "none";
  }

 }

 // call initialization file
 if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
  Init();
 }


})();
```

```css
/*
Styles for HTML5 File Drag & Drop demonstration
Featured on SitePoint.com
Developed by Craig Buckler (@craigbuckler) of OptimalWorks.net
*/
body
{
 font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Helvetica, freesans, sans-serif;
 font-size: 90%;
 margin: 10px;
 color: #333;
 background-color: #fff;
}

#filedrag
{
 display: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 1em 0;
 margin: 1em 0;
 color: #555;
 border: 2px dashed #555;
 border-radius: 7px;
 cursor: default;
}

#filedrag.hover
{
 color: #f00;
 border-color: #f00;
 border-style: solid;
 box-shadow: inset 0 3px 4px #888;
}

img
{
 max-width: 100%;
}

pre
{
 width: 95%;
 height: 8em;
 font-family: monospace;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 padding: 1px 2px;
 margin: 0 0 1em auto;
 border: 1px inset #666;
 background-color: #eee;
 overflow: auto;
}

#messages
{
 padding: 0 10px;
 margin: 1em 0;
 border: 1px solid #999;
}

#progress p
{
 display: block;
 width: 240px;
 padding: 2px 5px;
 margin: 2px 0;
 border: 1px inset #446;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: #eee url("progress.png") 100% 0 repeat-y;
}

#progress p.success
{
 background: #0c0 none 0 0 no-repeat;
}

#progress p.failed
{
 background: #c00 none 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>HTML5 File Drag &amp; Drop API</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="upload" action="index.html" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<fieldset>
<legend>HTML File Upload</legend>

<input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />

<div>
 <label for="fileselect">Files to upload:</label>
 <input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple" />
 <div id="filedrag">or drop files here</div>
</div>

<div id="submitbutton">
 <button type="submit">Upload Files</button>
</div>

</fieldset>

</form>

<div id="messages">
<p>Status Messages</p>
</div>


<script src="filedrag.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 提示いただいたコードは、実際にサーバーにファイルが送信・保存されるわけではなく、そのファイルの情報を表示するだけと見受けられます。その上で、「表示したファイル情報を個別に消すボタンの実装」についてお答えすればいいですか？

Comment: ＞「表示したファイル情‌​報を個別に消すボタンの実装」についてお答えすればい
いですか？
はい、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ちはみに、質問者さんはJavascriptについてどの程度経験がおありでしょうか。DOM操作やjQueryといった言葉はわかりますか？

Comment: はい、DOM操作やjQueryの意味を理解しております。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ここのサンプルコードのようですね。

[How to Use HTML5 File Drag and Drop](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-file-drag-and-drop/)

上のコードでファイル情報を生成しているのは `ParseFile()` ですが、HTMLを生成して `innerHTML` に追加しているので、個別にイベントハンドラを設定するのは少々面倒です。

なので、 `onclick="this.parentElement.remove()"` なボタンを `<p>` の中に入れるのが最短ではないでしょうか。

```js
/*
filedrag.js - HTML5 File Drag & Drop demonstration
Featured on SitePoint.com
Developed by Craig Buckler (@craigbuckler) of OptimalWorks.net
*/
(function() {

 // getElementById
 function $id(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
 }


 // output information
 function Output(msg) {
  var m = $id("messages");
  m.innerHTML = msg + m.innerHTML;
 }


 // file drag hover
 function FileDragHover(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.className = (e.type == "dragover" ? "hover" : "");
 }


 // file selection
 function FileSelectHandler(e) {

  // cancel event and hover styling
  FileDragHover(e);

  // fetch FileList object
  var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

  // process all File objects
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
   ParseFile(f);
  }

 }


 // output file information
 function ParseFile(file) {

  Output(
   "<p>File information: <strong>" + file.name +
   "</strong> type: <strong>" + file.type +
   "</strong> size: <strong>" + file.size +
   "</strong> bytes" +
   '<input type="button" onclick="this.parentElement.remove()" value="削除" />' +
   "</p>"
  );

 }


 // initialize
 function Init() {

  var fileselect = $id("fileselect"),
   filedrag = $id("filedrag"),
   submitbutton = $id("submitbutton");

  // file select
  fileselect.addEventListener("change", FileSelectHandler, false);

  // is XHR2 available?
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if (xhr.upload) {

   // file drop
   filedrag.addEventListener("dragover", FileDragHover, false);
   filedrag.addEventListener("dragleave", FileDragHover, false);
   filedrag.addEventListener("drop", FileSelectHandler, false);
   filedrag.style.display = "block";

   // remove submit button
   submitbutton.style.display = "none";
  }

 }

 // call initialization file
 if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
  Init();
 }


})();
```

```css
/*
Styles for HTML5 File Drag & Drop demonstration
Featured on SitePoint.com
Developed by Craig Buckler (@craigbuckler) of OptimalWorks.net
*/
body
{
 font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Helvetica, freesans, sans-serif;
 font-size: 90%;
 margin: 10px;
 color: #333;
 background-color: #fff;
}

#filedrag
{
 display: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 1em 0;
 margin: 1em 0;
 color: #555;
 border: 2px dashed #555;
 border-radius: 7px;
 cursor: default;
}

#filedrag.hover
{
 color: #f00;
 border-color: #f00;
 border-style: solid;
 box-shadow: inset 0 3px 4px #888;
}

img
{
 max-width: 100%;
}

pre
{
 width: 95%;
 height: 8em;
 font-family: monospace;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 padding: 1px 2px;
 margin: 0 0 1em auto;
 border: 1px inset #666;
 background-color: #eee;
 overflow: auto;
}

#messages
{
 padding: 0 10px;
 margin: 1em 0;
 border: 1px solid #999;
}

#progress p
{
 display: block;
 width: 240px;
 padding: 2px 5px;
 margin: 2px 0;
 border: 1px inset #446;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: #eee url("progress.png") 100% 0 repeat-y;
}

#progress p.success
{
 background: #0c0 none 0 0 no-repeat;
}

#progress p.failed
{
 background: #c00 none 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>HTML5 File Drag &amp; Drop API</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="upload" action="index.html" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<fieldset>
<legend>HTML File Upload</legend>

<input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />

<div>
 <label for="fileselect">Files to upload:</label>
 <input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple" />
 <div id="filedrag">or drop files here</div>
</div>

<div id="submitbutton">
 <button type="submit">Upload Files</button>
</div>

</fieldset>

</form>

<div id="messages">
<p>Status Messages</p>
</div>


<script src="filedrag.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

ただ個人的には文字列操作でHTMLを生成するよりjQueryで要素を生成して、そこにイベントも設定するのが好みではあります。

```
var elem = $('<p>');
// elemに諸々セット
var btn = $('<button>').appendTo(elem);
btn.on('click', function(){ ... });
elem.appendTo('#messages');
```

みたいな感じで。

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決することが出来ました。
記載していただいた二通りの方法どちらも試してみたいと思います。